# jquery make clickable url in rollover div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In the code bellow, I have the div appear on the mouse over effect. Is there away I can insert a url based on the data that gets passed to it?

```
Anchorage:  ["Anchorage", "(555)555-5555"], (This is the data that gets posted)
AtlanticCity:  ["Atlantic City", "(555)555-5555"],

                onMouseover: function (data) {
                    inArea = true;
                    $('#city-name').text(captions[data.key][0]);
                    $('#city-phone').text(captions[data.key][1]);
                },

<div id="city-caption" class="citycaption">
     <span class="cityname" id="city-name"></span>
     <span class="cityphone" id="city-phone"></span>  
</div>
```

Comment: Can you put your working code into a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to be confident without knowing more but I think you are looking for a way to have a clickable span.  For example:

```
$('#city-name').click(function(){window.location.href=data.url});
```

Comment: "It's hard to be confident without knowing more" - then flag for closure instead of answering, perhaps?

Comment: True, but I think I know what the user is looking for.  We just need more info.  I'll ask more questions next time.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking for, I didn't think to simply make the whole span clickable.

Comment: Yay!  Partial confidence++ :)